# Fatal Error: error when reading "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\libeay32.lib": unexpected end-of-file

Tags: c++, c, linker

i want to implement cryptographic algorithm to the arm at91sam7 micro. so i started with simple sha-1 openssl hash function. i could compile this sample code of sha-1 with code::block software and got true output. but when i want to use this code in my micro, i must compile and built it with arm compiler (for example IAR Workbench especially). i could compile the code in IAR truly but when i want to built it, i give no definitions errors. so i added C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\libeay32.lib to the linker additional library but i give this linker error:
'Fatal Error: error when reading "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\libeay32.lib": unexpected end-of-file'.
could every one help me?Appreciate the help.

my sample code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>           
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main (){

   EVP_MD_CTX sha1ctx;
  unsigned char sha1val[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
  unsigned int i, sha1len;
  char buf[2]="80";
  int numIn;
  EVP_DigestInit(&sha1ctx, EVP_sha1());  
    numIn=2;
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&sha1ctx, buf, numIn);
  EVP_DigestFinal(&sha1ctx, sha1val, &sha1len);

  printf("SHA1: ");
  for(i=0; i<sha1len; i++)
    printf("%02x", sha1val[i]);
  printf("\n");
  EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&sha1ctx);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The library `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\libeay32.lib` is probably for the wrong architecture.  You are cross-compiling for an embedded system target (`at91sam7`), use the library for that target.